# Where would arrays be used?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, simulation

> Suppose that a fast-food restaurant sells salad and burger. There are
>   two cashiers. With cashier 1, the number of seconds that it takes to
>   complete an order of salad is uniformly distributed in
>   {55,56,...,64,65}; and the number of seconds it takes to complete an
>   order of burger is uniformly distributed in {111,112,...,,129,130}.
>   With cashier 2, the number of seconds that it takes to complete an
>   order of salad is uniformly distributed in {65,66,...,74,75}; and the
>   number of seconds it takes to complete an order of burger is uniformly
>   distributed in {121,122,...,,139,140}. Assume that the customers
>   arrive at random times but has an average arrival rate of r customers
>   per minute.
>
> Consider two diﬀerent scenarios.
>
> • Customers wait in one
>   line for service and, when either of two cashiers is available, the
>   ﬁrst customer in the line goes to the cashier and gets serviced. In
>   this scenario, when a customer arrives at the restaurant, he either
>   gets serviced if there is no line up, or waits at the end of the line.
>
> • Customers wait in two lines, each for a cashier. The ﬁrst customer
>   in a line will get serviced if and only if the cashier for his line
>   becomes available. In this scenario, when a customer arrives at the
>   restaurant, he joins the shorter line. In addition, we impose the
>   condition that if a customer joins a line, he will not move to the
>   other line or to the other cashier when the other line becomes shorter
>   or when the other cashier becomes free.
>
> In both scenarios considered,
>   a cashier will only start serving the next customer when the customer
>   he is currently serving has received his ordered food. (That is the
>   point we call “the customer’s order is completed”.)
>
> ... Simulation
>
> For
>   each of the two scenarios and for several choices of r (see later
>   description), you are to simulate the customers
>   arriving/waiting/getting service over a period of 3 hours, namely,
>   from time 0 to time 180 minutes, where you assume that at time 0 there
>   is no customer waiting and both cashiers are available; The entire
>   period of 3 hours is to be divided into time slots each of 1 second
>   duration. At each time slot, with r/60 probability, you make one new
>   customer arrive, and with 1 − r/60 probability you make no new
>   customer arrive. This should give rise to an average customer arrival
>   rate of r customers/minute, and the arrival model will be reasonably
>   close to what is described above. In each time slot, you will make
>   your program handle whatever necessary.
>
> ... Objectives and
>   Deliverables
>
> You need to write a program to investigate the following.
>   For each of the two scenarios and for each r, you are to divide the
>   three-hour simulated period into 10-minute periods, and for every
>   customer arriving during period i (i ∈ {1,2,...,18}), compute the
>   overall waiting time of the customer (namely, from the time he arrives
>   at the restaurant to the time when his order is completed. You need to
>   print for each i the average waiting time for the customers arriving
>   during period i. Note that if a customer arriving in period i has not
>   been served within the three-hour simulated period, then his waiting
>   time is not known. So the average waiting time for customers arriving
>   in this period cannot be computed. In that case, simply print “not
>   available” as the average waiting time for that period.

So, this program deals with hours, minutes, and seconds.

Would it be best to make a three-dimensional array as such:

```
time[3][60][60]
```

A total of three hours, with 60 minutes within, with 60 seconds within.

Alternatively, I was thinking that I should make a "for-loop" with this structure:

```
for (time=0;t<10800;t++)
```

Every iteration of this loop will represent one second of the three hour simulation (3hx60mx60s=10800 seconds).

Am I on the right track here guys? Which method is more plausible. Are there other arrays that are critical for this program?

Help is appreciated, as always!

Comment: I'd handle it symbolically instead of using a tick based solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always best to have your internal representation of time be in seconds; you'll have a much easier time working with your for loop than with a three-dimensional array.  One nice convention is to write it as

```
MAX_SECONDS = 3 * 60 * 60
for (t=0;t<MAX_SECONDS;t++)
```

The data structure to look into for this project is, appropriately enough, a queue.  This can be implemented using arrays, but will require some extra work.